# Specifying the size of a vector in declaration vs using reserve

Tags: c++, stdvector

What is the difference between specifying the size of vector in declaration vs using reserve? My code seems to produce different results.

```
int main() {
    int n = 10;
    std::vector<int> arr(n);
    arr.push_back(0);
    arr.push_back(1);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int a = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
        arr.insert(arr.begin() + i, a);
    }
   std::cout << arr[3] << std::endl;
}
```

The above code prints 0

```
int main() {
    int n = 10;
    std::vector<int> arr;
    arr.reserve(n);
    arr.push_back(0);
    arr.push_back(1);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int a = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
        arr.insert(arr.begin() + i, a);
    }
   std::cout << arr[2] << std::endl;
}
```

This code prints 2 which is correct

Comment: `std::vector<int> arr(n); arr.push_back(0); arr.push_back(1);` -- Now print `arr.size()`, and that should give you a hint on what is going on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vector: initialization or reserve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928547/vector-initialization-or-reserve)

Comment: By doing this: `std::vector<int> arr(n);`, you're initiating 10 empty slots inside the vector; `.push_back()` doesn't fill said spots, it appends a value after them. So with aforesaid syntax, the 10 first slots will be empty and unreserved unless you decide to reserve them. For instance: `arr[0] = 5`, or: `arr.insert(arr.begin(), 5);`

Comment: Isn't `arr.begin() + i` just `arr.end()` here?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for the hint, it helped.

Comment: @SkillerDz So is insert the only keyword that can be used to insert elements into those empty slots?

Comment: @NicolasDusart It did help, but my doubt was better explained better in this thread. Thanks

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It is here, my original code was different and I just modified that code to make it a bit simpler.